# XPath Get tag before embedded tag

Tags: xpath

I've been trying to get this using xpath:

```
<h1>Text1<nobr>Text2</nobr></h1>
```

xpath("//h1") gets both texts. Can't seem to figure out how to only get Text1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should return *text node* that is *direct child* of `<h1>` :

```
//h1/text()
```

**<kbd>[`Demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/4nAaE0M3q)</kbd>**

**Output :**

```
Text1
```